# Amazon AWS Elastic Transcode createJob and readJob not returning Input DetectedProperties data

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I have some trouble with PHP AWS SDK

I need to get original video file dimensions, width and height. Reading documentation these data could be retrieved by reading result structure from createJob and readJob functions, but in "Input" section I get only one parameter, "Key" as the original input file name. Anyone use this function?

I start from HLS sample php from AWS official site. I have functions to create job with DASH (fmp4 container) and HLS (ts container). I use 5 presets to make 5 different version of a video input. 5 version for 5 resolution, from 420 to 1920. Everithing works well, but I'm not able to get "DetectedProperties" information

Info about the returned structure at
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/get-job.html

reading documentation seems that information I need to get about the source video must be placed in the response. But I get the response and the structure I expect to see is different. No "DetectedProperties" present.

This is the documentation about for example createJob:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-elastictranscoder-2012-09-25.html#createjob

What I would ask for to anyone knows deeply the PHP SDK is why the documentation says that I will found DetectedProperties in the result, data that must be automatically added from the Elastic Transcoder using the source file to encode, and I get a result without it.

I think it something like an issue, or if not the documentation is really poor about this. I search in web for hours something useful to solve the problem. And I write here because I found nothing...

Thanks to everyone could help

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution from my post on official AWS PHP github project.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/issues/1306

I need to call a readJob after job is finished. At this point data about source video become available and I will be able to read DetectedProperties fields.

Wasting time was due to a bad documentation, not correctly show how sdk works

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! you saved my time, calling readJob after 'jobComplete' is great solution

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add this as a comment rather than an answer.